# Exception has occurred: ImportError DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have two PCs both running Windows 10 64 bit, and I have installed Python 3.8.1 on both of the PCs along with Microsoft Visual Studio Code. The strange thing is that I am running into a PyQt5 import issue on only one of the PCs while the other can import fine.

In the PC that I am experiencing issue, I have created a project directory along with setting up an virtual environment by executing

```
virtualenv env
```

After that I activated my virtualenv

```
.\env.\Scripts\activate
```

Then I installed the PyQt5==5.14.1 and made a simple script

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

Upon executing this script I get the following error

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
File "C:\Python\POS\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

I have never experienced this error before, and I have tried the followings that did not solve this error:

1) Starting Visual Studio Code with administrator right
2) Try running the test2.py script using cmd

From the online search, it seems that this error can be related to using different architectures of Python and PyQt5, but I don't know how to troubleshoot further. I have verified that my Python 3.8.1 is 32 bit and I presume that pip install will automatically find the right package for me when I execute

```
pip install PyQt5
```

so it should be 32 bit as well? I am puzzled most by the other PC worked fine, and the setup both with regard on Python installation and virtual environment setup is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the problem by downgrading PyQt5

```
pip install PyQt5==5.13
```

However, still not sure why this problem occured in one of my Windows 10 computer while not on the other one with exact same Python installation and Visual Studio Code installation.